# I just learned about signed magnitude ,1's complement and 2's complement representation and I want to make sure that I understood them

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, data

So if I have the number 17 ( 8 bit code), the signed-magnitude representation is : 00010001
For -17 : 10010001
For 1's complement 17 = 00010001
For 1's complement -17 = 11101110
For 2's complement 17 = 00010001
For 2's complement -17 = 11101111
Please I need someone to tell me if it is correct.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yup.

You can test your 2's compliment math on a calculator that displays binary.  For $n$-bit numbers, you negate the number by subtracting it from (positive) $2^n$.

So -17, in 2's compliment, is 100000000 - 00010001 = 11101111.  Or subtract 17 from 256, and then display the result in binary.